# How do I make apache/php delete the temporary files created in /tmp?

Tags: php, apache

My webapp (PHP) creates some temp files in /tmp folder - while the creation works correctly, the deletion doesn't (I'm using an external library here, which creates these files, but unable to cleanup).  Is there any specific setting for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP command to delete a file is unlink:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

But you must have OS permission to delete a file.